# Adding a user to a domain group doesn't grant access in TFS Web Access

Tags: user-management, tfs-web-access

I am trying to give access to group of domain users (like All Developers) to team web access. I am able to add them to readers in team web access but when users try to access team web access it does not work. When I add users individually it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a job on the TFS server that expands these AD groups. It might take a while for that to happen if the group hasn't been synchronized to TFS before. The [default update frequency is 1hr and can be configured in the web.config on the TFS Application Tier](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fca050bd-70fc-4712-a310-1985295d72bb/windows-groups-tfs-does-not-see-new-users-until-restart?forum=tfsadmin) by setting it to a lower valueit will take less time for the user to appear.

Restarting the TFS server/services on the application tier will also trigger a refresh of the registered groups and users.

If the user was very recently added to this group, he might need to lock/unlock his windows session to make sure Windows updates the group membership. Alternatively logging off and back on should also update the client.

Answer (score -1):

Tell them to reboot their computer (the developer).  That always seems to work for me when I change somebodies AD groups and it's not taking effect quickly enough.

Comment: When I add developers individually it works but when I add them in there domain group like AllDevelopers its doesnot work